# How to get odd numbers of parameters in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, parsing, parameters, uri

Greetings everyone

Using the `request` object, I can't get a sole value as in this URI:

```
http://mydomain.com/controller/action/value1
```

Using `$request->getParams()` is not returning the `value1`.

Output:

```
array([controller] => 'controller', [action] => 'action')
```

The key is missing.

The issue itself is quite simple and I could parse the URI myself, but actually I want ZF to do it (right?). I couldn't find a hint using google or on SO.

How am I able to get a key without a value?

Comment: So routing is the trick ;) Thanks everyone, I ticked the most comprehensible answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For default, Zend Framework expects the parameters in URL to be in the form of `/key/value`. Try this:

http://mydomain.com/controller/action/key1/value1

```
print_r($request->getParams());
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [controller] => controller
    [action] => action
    [key1] => value1
)
```

Edit: as others mentioned, If you want to stick with `http://mydomain.com/controller/action/value1` you should take a look at [`Zend_Controller_Router`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your routes by adding the needed field.

Answer (score 0):

Well whats the route it looks like map to? If its the default route then this should be expected because it relies on the parsing rule `key/value`.

If it doesnt follow that simple rule then you need to create a new route to match the rule for that particular URI.

In general if you think you have a key that will not have a value you need to supply a default for that value in the route.

Answer (score 0):

http://mydomain.com/controller/action/param/value1/

```
array([controller] => 'controller', [action] => 'action', [param] => 'value1');
```

If you want this like iin your example you have to make your own route.

Answer (score 0):

By default, rails style URL parsing will be used. So for your purposes you would want:

```
http://mydomain.com/controller/action/key1/value1
```

You can configure the router though so that you would not have to use the key1 part. See the docs:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Answer (score 0):

Define your route in the routes.ini file as follows (if value1 is a decimal value, if not change the regular expression to fit your needs):

```
routes.your_route.route = "controller/action/:value1"
routes.your_route.defaults.controller = "controller"
routes.your_route.defaults.action = "action"
routes.your_route.reqs.value1 = "\d+"
```

Then you can access the value in your action using getParam(s).